# Django REST Framework JSON response on internal server error only for API calls

Tags: python, json, django, rest

I'm working on a large Django app that contains a REST API through DRF on a /api/ url. I'd like to make errors respond as JSON for all views called from the API, but still respond with HTML for normal requests to all the other URLs.

I'm aware you can use Middleware to handle all exceptions in the site, but is there a way to just use it for certain apps?

Thanks

Comment: need to skip some custom error , right?

Comment: you want to appears errors without using your own html ?

Comment: DRF does that by default, can you please provide an example of what you really need?